# Which portion of HTML code use for scraping a website table

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For the seguent url

> https://sports.bwin.com/it/sports#leagueIds=42&sportId=4
> I'd like to scrape a simple table of betting quotations.
> The problem is tha i don't know which part od HTML code to use (and also how use it).
> Here the table example:
> [image: Table to scrap]

I don't paste the html code 'cuse is too long to paste.
here's my code but i always get an empty object

```
my_url = "https://sports.bwin.com/it/sports#leagueIds=42&sportId=4"

 #opening up connection , grabbing page
 uClient = uReq(my_url)
 page_html = uClient.read()
 uClient.close()


header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36'}
page=requests.get(my_url,headers=header)
page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

betting = page_soup.findAll("table" , {"class": "marketboard-event-without-header__markets-list"})
```

Comment: I can't access the site (blocked for me), but my guess is the page is dynamic. I'd would try using selenium. You could also try pandas `pd.read_html()`, as if there are `<table>` tags, `pd.read_html()` uses beautifulsoup under the hood and would do the hard work for you

Comment: Do you expect everything in that image (except the bar charts)? Or just certain parts?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are trying to get is loaded dynamically.  In order to get the data you are trying to get you would need to make requests to the api that the page accesses for its data instead of getting the page itself.

The reason you are not getting the table in your beautiful soup is that the table is not in the original page source, but it is loaded after the page is loaded in the client.

If you mimic the requests that load the data you should be able to get the data from those subsquent requests.